# starting my own threads within python paste

Tags: python, pylons, paste

I'm writing a web application using pylons and paste. I have some work I want to do after an HTTP request is finished (send some emails, write some stuff to the db, etc) that I don't want to block the HTTP request on.

If I start a thread to do this work, is that OK? I always see this stuff about paste killing off hung threads, etc. Will it kill my threads which are doing work?

What else can I do here? Is there a way I can make the request return but have some code run after it's done?

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you see 'paste killing off hung threads' ?

Comment: 18:59:29,042 INFO  [paste.httpserver.ThreadPool] kill_hung_threads status: 10 threads (0 working, 10 idle, 0 starting) ave time N/A, max time 0.00sec, killed 0 workers

Answer (score 0):

You could use a thread approach (maybe setting the [Thead.daemon](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon) property would help--but I'm not sure).

However, I would suggest looking into a task queuing system.  You can place a task on a queue (which is very fast), then a listener can handle the tasks asynchronously, allowing the HTTP request to return quickly.  There are two task queues that I know of for Django:

- [Django Queue Service](http://code.google.com/p/django-queue-service/wiki/DjangoQueueService)
- [Celery](http://ask.github.com/celery/introduction.html)

You could also consider using an more "enterprise" messaging solution, such as [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) or [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/).

**Edit**: [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454944/advice-on-python-django-and-message-queues/455024#455024) with some good pointers.

Comment: celery is not just for Django anymore, some people have already used it with Pylons.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is messaging system because it can be configured to not loose the task if the pylons process goes down. I would always use processes over threads especially in this case. If you are using python 2.6+ use the built in [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) or you can always install the processing module which you can find on pypi (I can't post link because of I am a new user).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at gearman, it was specifically made for farming out tasks to 'workers' to handle. They can even handle it in a different language entirely. You can come back and ask if the task was completed, or just let it complete. That should work well for many tasks.

If you absolutely need to ensure it was completed, I'd suggest queuing tasks in a database or somewhere persistent, then have a separate process that runs through it ensuring each one gets handled appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your basic question directly, you should be able to use threads just as you'd like.  The "killing hung threads" part is paste cleaning up its own threads, not yours.

There are other packages that might help, etc, but I'd suggest you start with simple threads and see how far you get.  Only then will you know what you need next.

(Note, "Thread.daemon" should be mostly irrelevant to you here.  Setting that true will ensure a thread you start will not prevent the entire process from exiting.  Doing so would mean, however, that if the process exited "cleanly" (as opposed to being forced to exit) your thread would be terminated even if it wasn't done its work.  Whether that's a problem, and how you handle things like that, depend entirely on your own requirements and design.